# How to select a value from a drop down menu

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, mouseover, pageobjects

I want to select the option from the drop-down menu. I tried a number of ways but I failed.

I tried:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("iMacs")));

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("iMacs")));
    waitForElementToBeDisplayed(driver.findElement(By.linkText("iMacs")), 200);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[text()='iMacs']")));
```

This is my code:

```
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Product Category"));
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.moveToElement(element).perform();
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 5);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("iMacs")));
            WebElement subElement = driver.findElement(By.linkText("iMacs"));
            action.moveToElement(subElement);
            action.click();
            action.perform();
```

This is my error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.linkText: iMacs (tried for 5 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
```

Comment: Please share html snippet in order to help!

Answer (score 0):

So you are hovering over some element and then trying to click on specific link? Which driver are you using? Do you actually see that this menu is correctly rendered after hover?

Your code fails on `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("iMacs")));`

Try with `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("iMacs")));` instead and see if it fails then (and what exception it throws in that case).

And why are you using Actions API to perform click?

Comment: The same error. I use this because I do not know what else to try. I am a beginner in testing. Do you have another solution?

Comment: Ok, see my update and these 3 questions. For clicking you can use `subElement.click()` instead of those 3 action lines.

Comment: I use chrome driver. My test doing whatever wait to use than what I stated that I used, the problem is that sometimes fall test, used to pass.

Comment: And what happens if you completely remove this line of code: `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("iMacs")));` ? Paste exception that you get in this case.

Comment: When you delete line of code: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"iMacs"} (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: It seems that this "iMacs" link is not present on the page but it's hard for me to help because I can't see your page or test execution. You should debug it, see how much it takes for element to show after you perform hover action.

Comment: I test this site: http://store.demoqa.com/ . Perhaps you mean something to better understand what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I tried executing your code in Chrome and it always worked for me. However, as sometimes, it is failing for you, you can put recovery mechanism in your code, as shown below:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Product Category"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).perform();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 5);
try {
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("iMacs")));
} catch (WebDriverException we) {
       System.out.println("First attempt to wait for visibility of 'iMacs' failed. Retrying...");
       action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Product Category"))).perform();
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("iMacs")));
}
WebElement subElement = driver.findElement(By.linkText("iMacs"));
action.moveToElement(subElement);
action.click();
action.perform();
```

Above code should always work. Please let me know, if you have any further queries.

Comment: I do not need to click on the drop-down menu, I just need to move through the menu. This site test: http://store.demoqa.com/ .

Comment: Please try the modified code and let me know, if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `sendkeys` option also. May be this help in your code.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("code']")).sendKeys("testdata");
```